# PHP implementation of MySql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

**test_pattern with column:**

- id,url,creator

**test_map with column**

- id, url
- example data

  - id:1, url:"www.abc/"
  - id:2, url:"www.abc/?a=b"
  - id:3, url:"www.abc/testing"

I have a website that retrieve a **list of urls** from **test_map**, and user are able to choose a url to insert into **test_pattern**

- Now, when a user select a **url** to add it should check with **test_map** and add the relevant url with querystings
- Example, when select **"www.abc/"** it should add **"www.abc/"** and **"www.abc/?a=b"**.
- Lastly, if url already exist in test_pattern, it shouldn't be added

I'd came our with a working sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT NULL as id, url as url, "Ronny" as creator 
from test_map where url LIKE '%www.abc/?%') as tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT pattern FROM test_pattern WHERE pattern LIKE '%www.abc/?%');
```

However i don't know how to implement it in php, this is what i tried:

```
$sql = array(
sprintf('INSERT INTO %s SELECT * FROM (SELECT NULL as id, url as url, %s as creator FROM test_map WHERE url LIKE '%%s%') 
AS tmp', "'".$creator."'", "'".$url."?'".
' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test_pattern WHERE url LIKE '%'.sprintf('%s',"'".$url."?'").'%') LIMIT 1'
);
```

Please assist on php implementation of the sql statement. Thanks

Comment: are you using any **mysqli_** functions ? please mention.

Comment: you need connect to your database and need to execute query then after. For more http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Answer (score 0):

Set URL field in test_pattern as unique and then just do

```
 WHERE url LIKE '$url%'
```

No need to test for the value if exists in test_pattern

Comment: Actually there are more column which i have to check, it should be **creator** and **url** combination should be unique, which means same **url** but different **creator** is acceptable. Hence i did not edit as unique field.

Comment: i see its no problem if you did it like this. but then i would say to break the code into check and then add else you can use insert with select

Comment: i have found the issue, issue is **%%s%**, i can't use `%s` in `LIKE '%%'` , however, i don't know what way can i insert `%s` in `LIKE '%%'`

Comment: hmm try %s in your string and $url% in your parameters. See sprintf example here http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_sprintf.asp Otherwise do it without sprintf just as generic string build

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, we can't use `%s` directly in `LIKE` like this **%%s%**.

To past value in between `%%`, we need to do this `%%%s%%`